# Log multiple uwsgi logger to stdout

Tags: django, logging, stdout, uwsgi

I'm running uwsgi inside a Docker container for a Django application. I want to log uwsgi, request, and django logs differently, so I created the following configuration in my `.ini` file.

```
[uwsgi]
logger = main file:/dev/stdout
logger = django file:/dev/stdout
logger = req file:/dev/stdout

log-format = "method": "%(method)", "uri": "%(uri)", "proto": "%(proto)", "status": %(status), "referer": "%(referer)", "user_agent": "%(uagent)", "remote_addr": "%(addr)", "http_host": "%(host)", "pid": %(pid), "worker_id": %(wid), "core": %(core), "async_switches": %(switches), "io_errors": %(ioerr), "rq_size": %(cl), "rs_time_ms": %(msecs), "rs_size": %(size), "rs_header_size": %(hsize), "rs_header_count": %(headers), "event": "uwsgi_request"

log-route = main ^((?!django).)*$
log-route = django django
log-route = req uwsgi_request

log-encoder = format:django ${msg}
log-encoder = nl:django

log-encoder = json:main {"timestamp": "${strftime:%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S+00:00Z}", "message":"${msg}","severity": "INFO"}
log-encoder = nl:main

log-encoder = format:req {"timestamp": "${strftime:%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S}", ${msg}}
log-encoder = nl:req
```

The problem is that now my logs for my `django` and `req` don't show up. I'm guessing that's because multiple loggers want to write to `/dev/stdout` and can't.

How can I 1. Write everything to `stdout` while 2. Formatting my logs differently based on a regex?

---

I confirmed this is the case by turning of some of the log routes and seeing everything work.

Comment: Actually, it seems anything that is captured by `log-route` doesn't show up, which means that probably my reference to `/dev/stdout` is wrong somehow.

Comment: In my local I can rewrite them to `/dev/tty`, but that doesn't work in my docker container :(

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not: https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout

Comment: `logger` should be like `logger = {LOGGER_NAME} stdio` (`stdio` instead of `file:/dev/stdout`).